# android : how to know setting up layout is finished to call getLocalVisibleRect

Tags: android, android-layout

I am calling getLocalVisibleRect() and it is returning all 0s and
i got to know the reason as  from other questions :

" need to wait until android is finished setting up the layout before using getLocalVisibleRect, if you call it in OnCreate it won't work" .

My question is how can i know the layout is finished. I have a lineralayout and i am trying to draw some objects on it. I dont want to define any onclick listener. I want the items to be drawn as soon as the layout setting is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how can i know the layout is finished

check out [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html).

Every view has one and it has a bunch of callback interfaces that will be called when drawing is done or when layout is done (see [ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html))

Something like this:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = myView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
     void onGlobalLayout() {
       //your callback code
     }
});
```

Comment: i have not tested it as i changed my code and no longer use this .Thanks for the answer